# Model using different random seeds leads to different interpretation result

Tags: survival-analysis, cox-regression, shap

I'm currently utilizing the `shap` library to interpret a hybrid model that combines a Cox proportional hazards model with a Multi-Layer Perceptron (MLP) using the `pycox` library. Interestingly, the neural network version of model outperforms the conventional linear Cox proportional hazards model. However, I'm facing an issue with the `shap.DeepExplainer` as it provides different interpretations when the models have different random seeds. This variability makes it challenging for me to obtain a stable result and draw conclusions about the most and least contributing features.

I'm seeking guidance on how to address this inconsistency in interpretations. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I am not sure the approaches described below make sense, but these are the potential ways that I can imagine to partially tackle the problem:

1. **Mostly naive:** only use the model with the highest score (in my case, the concordance index). But how should I explain other models with the different random seeds and different interpretation results.
2. **Average multiple interpretation results:** Given multiple random seeds, just calculate the average SHAP values of each feature using all the results of different models. But is this scientific and popular?

Comment: SHAP is deterministic against your model. Fix you model's seed and you'll get the same SHAP values.

Comment: Hi Sergey! I know that same SHAP values will get with fixed random seed. But what I want to ask is under different seeds, the SHAP values are different, therefore my interpretation of the result is inconsistent between models with different seeds.

Comment: As I said already, SHAP values are not attributes of data. They are explanations of a model. Different models will lead to different interactions among features in how a model predicts. And even the same model with different seed may produce different results. Fix your model and you'll get what you want (ie stability in SHAP values)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations and patience!

Comment: You should worry more about the instability of the model instead of the instability of the SHAP values.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I agree that first reducing the instability of the model might lead to a more consistency on the result of the SHAP value. I also find one paper "Agree to Disagree: When Deep Learning Models With Identical Architectures Produce Distinct Explanations" (https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.06791) arguing the same problem. So I think improving the model is the best way :)